# Trying to shorten check conditions using or in ng-if directive. Comparing series value with multiple times as there are many values to check in or

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-1.5, angularjs-ng-if

```
<img src="img/temp.png" class="img-responsive" ng-if="series === 'Temperature' || series === 'T' || series === 'Temperature-138828'">
```

I tried like this, but it didn't work:

```
<img src="img/temp.png" class="img-responsive" ng-if="series === ('Temperature' || 'T' || 'Temperature-138828')">
```

Is there a way to shorten this `<img>` tag (such as to compare series with multiple values or something else?). I haven't used angularjs a lot, so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes. Call a function, and put that code in the function, in your controller.

Comment: Even better, pre-calculate the result when you initialize (or change) the `series` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<img src="img/temp.png" class="img-responsive" ng-if="['Temperature', 'T', 'Temperature-138828'].indexOf(series) > -1">
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should take that compare to a function in controller.
You can create constant array there, and check does series in that array.

P.s.
TemeratureArray declare as condtant.
Use vm, not scope (but in first staps you can try with scope)